# django TemplateDoesNotExist, generated urls

Tags: python, django, url

I need to create links through the title and load a template noticia_detail.html generated per link, but I have a problem is the following:

I was looking error and I think the problem is in the settings file, templates_path or something, help me please

For every URL generate by slug i request, it throws:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /noticia/crea-horario/
infogeneral/noticia_detail.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:1280/noticia/crea-horario/
Django Version: 1.7.1
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
infogeneral/noticia_detail.html
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in select_template, line 194
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\PC\\Documents\\python\\taskalertproyect\\taskalert',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-1.4.2-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django_fiber-0.11.2-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\easy_thumbnails-1.4-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\djangorestframework-2.3.8-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django_compressor-1.3-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pillow-2.2.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\six-1.5.2-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django_appconf-0.6-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pyopenssl-0.14-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Python27',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Lun, 3 Nov 2014 01:10:43 -0500

Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
C:\home\taskalertproyect\taskalert\infogeneral\templates\infogeneral\noticia_detail.html (File does not exist)
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\infogeneral\noticia_detail.html (File does not exist)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\infogeneral\noticia_detail.html (File does not exist)
C:\Users\PC\Documents\python\taskalertproyect\taskalert\infogeneral\templates\infogeneral\noticia_detail.html (File does not exist)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_markdown\templates\infogeneral\noticia_detail.html (File does not exist)
```

index.html

```
<section class="content">
                {% for noticia in pagina.noticia.all %}
                    <article>
                        <div class="post">
                            <h1 class="title">
                                <a href="/noticia/{{noticia.slug}}/">{{ noticia.titulo_noticia}}</a>
                            </h1>
                            <p>{{ noticia.contenido_noticia|safe }}<p>
                            <a class="read_more" href="/noticia/{{noticia.slug}}/">Continue Reading <i class="read_more_arrow"></i> </a>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                {% endfor %}
            </section><!-- Content End -->
```

noticia_detail.html

```
<h2>{{ object.titulo_noticia }}</h2>
<p>{{ object.contenido_noticia }}</p>
```

urls.py

```
from infogeneral.views import NoticiaDetailView
url(r'^noticia/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', NoticiaDetailView.as_view(),name='noticia_detail')
```

models.py

```
class Noticia(models.Model):
    titulo_noticia = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.titulo_noticia)
        super(Noticia, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Noticia

class NoticiaDetailView(DetailView):
    tamplate_name = 'noticia_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'noticias'
    model = Noticia
```

settings.py

```
TEMPLATES_URL = '/templates/'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    'C:/Users/PC/Documents/python/taskalertproyect/taskalert/infogeneral/templates',
)
```

Comment: Why are you using a Linux "/home/taskalertproyect..." path when you are on a Windows machine and your project is in "c:/Users/PC/Documents/python/taskalertproyect"?

Comment: Thanks and apply the changes but still the same

Answer (score 0):

Your template can not be loaded. Django tries to load it from the positions given at the bottom of the error message but could not find it there. Make sure the template is in the right position. Right position would be on `C:\Users\PC\Documents\python\taskalertproyect\taskalert\infogeneral\templates\infogeneral\noticia_detail.html` according to the error message.

Also your settings seem to reflect a UNIX/Linux system, but the output indicated Windows. You should update the paths.

Comment: ty, i change for all directoris but i not match any result, i'll check path.